# ghci only loads with admin

Tags: haskell, cmd, ghci

I've been trying to install Haskell platform with chocolatey but have been unable to get it working without running the command prompt as an administrator.

When I do so normally it just states that "ghci is not recognized as an internal or external command", but when I do so with admin privileges' it works fine.

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156569/stack-ghci-cant-load-pthread-unless-running-as-administrator) and attempted to add the pthread.dll file to my system but this seemed to just make the program run worse as admin. I'm confused why something that should be so basic as setting up a programming language is giving me so much headache

Comment: This needs way more info. Operating system, versions, commands you tried, what exactly happened in each case...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Running Windows 10 Pro, running ghci ver 8.10.3, literally running "ghci" just causes the cmd to state " 'ghci' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" no error message or anything, that's it

Comment: I'm curious: are the versioned executables (e.g. `ghc-8.10.3`, `ghci-8.10.3`) available?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not sure, where would I find these executables?

Comment: @MakoriSM I mean: you say you can't run `ghci`. But can you run `ghci-8.10.3`?

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't know, how would I go about trying to run that? You spoke of an executable, where would I find this executable file?

Comment: @MakoriSM I am *specifically* asking: if you try to run `ghci-8.10.3` in *exactly the same* way that you tried running `ghci` (whatever that was), what happens?

Comment: @DanielWagner The exact same thing happens, " 'ghci-8.10.3' is not recognized as an internal command..."

Comment: Okay. My gut reaction is that the chocolatey installer is intended to modify your `PATH` environment variable (maybe on Windows it's called `%PATH%` or something?), but didn't for some reason. There are instructions various places on the web for checking out your environment variables, and chocolatey should have documentation about where it installs things; perhaps you can look into whether those two pieces match up in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to fix it by making an environment variable directly to my `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc\tools\ghc-8.10.3\bin` location.

I thought making an environment variable to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\` would have been sufficient but clearly not. Weird too as Chocolatey added many of its own environment variables but not one that pointed to gchi